# update new value to key in dictionary (python)

Tags: python

I make a minimised DFA, to use key value style coding, I used dictionary.

so there is a dictionary,

```
{1: {1:2}}
```

I want to update this dictionary add 2:3 to add key 1's dictionary.

```
{1: {1:2, 2:3}}
```

I don't know how to do this.

Is any simple idea to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `update()`:

```
In [27]: dic={1: {1:2}}

In [28]: dic[1].update({2:3})

In [29]: dic
Out[29]: {1: {1: 2, 2: 3}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I finished my programming project :)

Answer (score 0):

`dict[1][2] = 3`

It accesses the first dictionary that's indexed at `1`, then assigns the `2` key of this dict to `3`.